# Linked-server query against remote DB does NOT fail when DB is in SINGLE_USER mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, linked-server

This is really strange to me.  I have a primary server `Foo2005` and it has a linked-server entry pointing to `Bar2008R2`; say the name of the linked-server is `BarLINK`.  I write a query such as `SELECT * FROM BarLINK.MyDB.dbo.Stuff`.  The catch is, over on `Bar`, `MyDB` is in `SINGLE_USER` mode.  Why would this query still succeed?  I would expect to get the error like "Could not open the specified database since it's in SINGLE_USER mode and is already open by a user" (forgive me for not remembering the exact phraseology).

Notes:

1. Linked-server is created using a SQL login/pwd, say `readonly`, which, as the name implies, has READ permissions on the target server & DB.
2. Testing the query when `MyDB` is in `MULTI_USER` mode seems "faster" than when it runs & `MyDB` is in `SINGLE_USER` mode, but I don't have any concrete metric of that, just the observation/feels.
3. As the names indicate, server `Foo2005` (the "local" server where the query lives) is SQL 2005, while server `Bar2008R2` (the "remote" server where the query is being sent / where `MyDB` lives) is 2008R2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the User in the linked server the same as the user that has the db in single user mode?

Comment: Being in single user mode will not implicitly prevent you from connecting. If it is the only connection to the database when you would still be able to access it. Have you tried maintaining a connection with SSMS and then attempting to access data via the linked server?

Comment: @WEI_DBA no, I'm logged in to `Bar2008R2` & connected to `MyDB` as myself, a Windows login with admin rights.

Comment: @Nic It's possible that nobody else was connected to `MyDB` at the time, not even me.  I may have to test that theory.

Comment: Have you considered using restricted user instead of single user?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have not, but that's interesting. My goal was basically to prevent all other users from accessing it, without taking it offline. In this case there are several other users in the `db_owner` role so `restricted_user` doesn't _sound_ like a great fit, but... maybe.

Comment: The problem with single user is that you only get one. This often gets stolen away by SQL Server Agent or another user you're not expecting. Why are so many people in the db_owner role?

Comment: @AaronBertrand "Why" indeed.  Not really the point, tho.  I cannot seem to reproduce the problem so I'm going to close my question.  Thanks for the tips guys!

Comment: Well, it is the point. You could use restricted_user if you didn't have so many users with elevated rights.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47784/discussion-between-natej-and-aaron-bertrand).

Answer (score 0):

Upon re-trying and attempting to reproduce this problem, it seems I cannot.  I think [Nic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153792/linked-server-query-against-remote-db-does-not-fail-when-db-is-in-single-user-mo?noredirect=1#comment293593_153792) said it best so far: "being in single-user mode doesn't implicitly prevent connections".  At the time, the linked-server query must have been the first and only thing connecting to that DB.

Thanks also to [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153792/linked-server-query-against-remote-db-does-not-fail-when-db-is-in-single-user-mo?noredirect=1#comment293596_153792) for suggesting the `restricted_user` mode for future cases.